# How to uninstall Powershell 5.0 from Windows 7?

Tags: powershell, uninstallation, powershell-5.0

I have been searching it for a long time but didn't found any answers to it.
I have also checked powershell.org and found this solution : **wusa /uninstall /kb:2969050**
but when i tried , it came out with the result that this update was not installed on my computer.

Comment: The [WMF5.0 download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395) has a different kb id under Details. Ditto for [WMF5.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53347).

Answer (score 1):

you have to uninstall the 'windows management framework 5.0'

Comment: Thanks.. It worked :)